# Is there a way to limit the downloads for an app on the play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I am getting to launch a new app which is network based. Right now I do not have it scaled very large (I only have one server running). Is there anyway through Google Play that I can restrict the downloads to a couple of hundred people until I can purchase the scalability I need for my app? I want to have a maximum of a couple hundred people download the app a month so that I can scale accordingly. Is there anyway to do this besides removing it from the store every time I get too many downloads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could utilize [Google Play Alpha/Beta testing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) which allows you to invite people to either a Google Group or Google+ Community and only those people can download your application from Google Play. That way you could cut off membership once you've hit a certain number of people (note that if you are using a Google+ Community, you want to make sure you make it Public - Moderator approval to join or Private) and then restart once you've scaled up.

However, if you are doing a traditional production publish of your app then there is no way to limit the number of people downloading your application.